# What can we say about this quantity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\phi(n)$ be the Euler phi-function. If $a>1$ is an integer, then what is the remainder when $\phi(a^n - 1)$ is divided by $n$ in accordance with the Euclidean algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/(a^n-1)\mathbb{Z})^\times$ has an element of order $n$, namely $\overline{a}$, because obviously
$$a^n\equiv 1\bmod (a^n-1),$$
and $a^k\not\equiv 1\bmod (a^n-1)$ for any $0<k<n$ because $1<a^k-1<a^n-1$ for any $0<k<n$.

Because the group has an element of order $n$, the order of the group is divisible by $n$.

Since $\varphi(N)=|(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times|$, we have that $\varphi(a^n-1)$ is divisible by $n$. Thus the remainder is $0$.